# Mouse Actions and Listeners in Win API C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I learned Mouse actions and mouse listeners in Java, but not in C++. Anybody know how to do it?

The documentation for [`SetCapture()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262.aspx) says:

> This will cause all mouse messages to be routed toward your app's window.

This seems to be the listener function, but I wonder if it can be trimmed down to only listening for one mouse message?

By mouse actions, I mean a mouse click ("mouse left button down and mouse left button up"), moving the mouse to a certain position, etc.

Comment: C++ has no concept of "mouse", winapi has only a marginal one. It's there, but trust me it's an expletive deleted to write this stuff from raw Windows API primitives. [Recommend looking into Winforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) or similar GUI builder framework.

Comment: `SetCapture` is *not* a "mouse listener function."

Comment: In Windows, you create a window, and that window has a window procedure, and the window procedure is called when something happens to window - such as the user moving the mouse over it.

Comment: Look at window messages like `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`UP`, etc.  See [Mouse Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645533.aspx) for details.

Comment: @user4581301: What sort of abstractions for mouse input do you have in mind, that Windows Forms offers, but the Windows API doesn't?

Comment: What Java toolkit did you use, AWT, Swing, JavaFX, SWT?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : Thank you. This answers my question. Please repost your answer.